# How to do multiple groupings with a concrete class?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, group-by

I have this scenario.

I want group on Country and Category.

```
A store can have many countries and a country can have many stores. (many to many)
A store can have many categories and a category can have many stores (many to many)
```

Say I have these Categories

```
Food
Gas
Car Shop
```

I have these Stores

```
Pizza Hut
Canadian Tire
Shell
```

I have these Countries

```
Canada
USA
```

So in the end it should look like this

```
Canada
 Food
   Pizza Hut
 Gas
  Canadian Tire (some places have gas stations)
  Shell
 Car Shop
  Canadian Tire
USA
  Food
    Pizza Hut
  Gas
   Shell
  Car Shop
   (nothing in my example as Canadian Tire is only in Canada)
```

Above is pretty much the end result I want to show the user. I am stuck right now on grouping in linq ( I am also using nhibernate)

```
 session.Query<Store>().FetchMany(x => x.Countries).FetchMany(x => x.Categories).GroupBy(x => new {x.Countires, x.Categories})
```

The above would give me an anonymous class back but I need to return the results from the service layer and then use them to make my view Model.

So I can't use an anonymous class.

I am not sure how to make my concrete class?

Does it need to have like an Igrouping or something in there?

Comment: Not sure if your description of the model is consistent. You are saying that a shop can belong to several countries. Strange...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Yes a store can be in multiple countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an anonymous class because you are using the [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501) method. GroupBy in `IQueryable` works almost like SQL `GROUP BY` clause. In order to better understand grouping, you must consider that SQL GROUP BY can be used **only** with many-to-one operators like `SUM`, `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN` because they return a single result from a row set. Your concept of "grouping", in my opinion, is visual grouping on the GUI.

It has no sense to select all people (Name, Surname) and `GROUP BY` surname, because the choice of the name to project on the final result is ambiguous.

The GroupBy operator is exactly what you don't want to use. If you correctly established a many-to-one+many-to-one relationship (which forms a many-to-many) then you should have something like

```
public class Country{

    Store[] stores;
}

public class Store {
    Category[] categories;
    Country[] countries;
}

public class Category {
    Store[] stores;
}
```

The best way to "group" values is use plain old `for` loops. Here is **pseuso-C#** code

```
for (Country co in session.Query<Country>()) {
    Console.WriteLine(co); //Possibly c.Name or whatever
    Console.Indentation++; //.NET has not such a method but you understand what it means
    for (Category ca in co.Categories) {
        Console.WriteLine(ca);
        Console.Indentation++;
        for (Store s in ca.Stores) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.Indentation--;
    }
    Console.Indentation--;
}
```

[Add] example of a reverse lookup, which applies if your model says that there is a reference Category->Country but not Country->Category

```
   for (Country co in session.Query<Country>()) {
        Console.WriteLine(co);
        Console.Indentation++;
        for (Category ca in session.Query<Category>().Where(x => x.Country.equals(co))) {
            Console.WriteLine(ca);
            //snip
        }
        Console.Indentation--;
    }
```

Comment: Yes what I showed was visual to see what the end result will look like. To me thought it seemed to make sense you have a store and you can group it many different ways so that's why a groupby seemed to make sense to me.

Comment: GroupBy and SQL GROUP BY return *lists*, you actually needed a *tree* of objects (one object associated to many). I think this better helps you understand the differences. If you have more conceptual questions on grouping in RDBMS world feel free to ask on SO, perhaps you can find good explanations

Comment: I also don't get the first line of you code. How did you get Country. Would it not get Store first since your querying stores?

Comment: The first line of code comes natural after our definition of tree. In an hierarchical view, it is Country->Category->Store, so we need to "retrieve countries" first. Since all objects are in the same DB I choose to directly query countries because I don't need stores right now.

Comment: But you have session.Query<Store>() not session.Query<Country>();

Comment: Ok but I still think there is something missing. How does co.Categories get called when Country has no reference to Categories(what is correct it does not).

Comment: In a correct many-to-many relationship, Country has references to Categories. Otherwise you need to do a reverse lookup (example in answer)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by correct many to many. My many to many are correct. The categories are always the same no matter for what country I don't think a many to many is needed for it.

Comment: By "correct" I mean that your DB has a bridge table between involved entities and each class has a reference to an array of the associated entity. What you are now saying means that either your design or your code is broken. I'm starting to think that you want a completely different thing. Can you please show your HBM files and your table layout?

Answer (score 2):

If you define a class say, MyClass, with the right properties and an appropriate constructor can just use  new MyClass(x.Countries, x.Categories) in your query instead of the anonymous type constructor.

Or you can just use the default constructor with no parameters, and use the normal C# property initialisation syntax. My phone won't do curly brackets though so I can't post a code snippet :-(

Comment: When you can. Please post a code snippet as it will make it easier for me to fully understand what your saying.